# Знак препинания вместо "то"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

*В последний раз когда я так делал() я проигрывал.*

Здесь возможна постановка и тире, и запятой?

Comment: Перед "когда" запятая в любом случае нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что сочетание "в последний раз" и "проигрывал" представляется некорректным. Если это был последний раз, то и проигрыш, вероятно, подразумевается единичный. А что касается знака препинания, запятая, я выбираю тебя. И перед "когда" и после "делал".

Comment: Не моё предложение.Цитата из СМИ. Спасибо.